# React router params not passing

Tags: react-router, react-redux

I am trying to go to page and pass id, but my ownParams in mapStatetoProps remains empty. Do note the url generated is correct.

My current structure is

index.jsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.jsx

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Router />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

router.jsx

```
const Router = () => (
  <router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
      <Route path='/browse' component={Browse}/>
      <Route path='/detail/:id' component={Detail} />
    </Switch>
  </router>
)

export default Router;
```

detail.jsx

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Info />
        <Message/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Now in info.jsx at the end of the file

```
function mapStateToProps({posts}, ownProps){
    console.log('>>>>>>>> post_show State to props', ownProps);
    return { post : posts[ownProps.match.params.id]};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost, deletePost })(PostsShow);
```

this gives me an error because ownProps is empty.